# Why does MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL return nil

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

Why is the url of the music `nil`?

```
MPMediaPlaylist *playlist = [self.musicCollection objectAtIndex:cindex];
MPMediaItem *item = [playlist.items objectAtIndex:mindex];
NSUrl *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] ;
NSLog(@"URL == %@");
```

Why does it log `url = nil` ?

Comment: did you find the solution of this problem?